# How do I prevent rpm(build) from changing the access rights of config files during an update installation

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I use a RPM spec which contains lines very similar to the following:

```
...
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%attr(0666,root,root) %config /etc/myapp/myconfig.ini
...
```

The problem I encounter if someone installs an update of the RPM is that the access mode of /etc/myapp/myconfig.ini is wrong:

```
ur@test1:~> ls -l /etc/myapp/myconfig.ini
---------- 1 daemon root 1207 2012-10-29 17:16 /etc/myapp/myconfig.ini
```

So the application can't access it any longer. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: There is something else going on here i.e some post script or some app initialization script is doing something with your configuration script. I suspect that from different users in ls output (daemon, root) and not (root, root).

Comment: @rakesh.pandit: Thank you for your comment. Will investigate further, but currently I have other work to do.